# Storing coordinates of the max sub matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, coordinates

Programming a maximal size sub matrix containing only 1's from a binary matrix. I found a great explanation of how to do this at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-rectangle-binary-sub-matrix-1s/amp/

It finds it and prints out the size of the area. However, what it doesn't do is store/keep track of coordinates of that sub matrix, which would be much more useful to me in understanding the code better.

As I am a very fresh beginner in Python I could not find an appropriate explanation that I could understand "in my language". Any form of explanation would help!

Code (taken from geeksforgeeks):

```py
def maxHist(row): 
    # Create an empty stack. The stack holds indexes of hist array/ The bars stored   
    # in stack are always in increasing order of their heights.  
    result = [] 
    top_val = 0     # Top of stack  
    max_area = 0 # Initialize max area in current row (or histogram)  
    area = 0 # Initialize area with current top  
    # Run through all bars of given histogram (or row)  
    i = 0
    while (i < C):  
        # If this bar is higher than the  
        # bar on top stack, push it to stack  
        if (len(result) == 0) or (row[result[0]] <= row[i]): 
            result.append(i) 
            i += 1
        else: 
            # If this bar is lower than top of stack, then calculate area of rectangle with  
            # stack top as the smallest (or minimum height) bar. 'i' is 'right index' for  
            # the top and element before top in stack is 'left index'  
            top_val = row[result[0]]  
            result.pop(0)  
            area = top_val * i  
            if (len(result)): 
                area = top_val * (i - result[0] - 1 )  
            max_area = max(area, max_area)  
    # Now pop the remaining bars from stack and calculate area with every popped 
    # bar as the smallest bar  
    while (len(result)): 
        top_val = row[result[0]]  
        result.pop(0)  
        area = top_val * i  
        if (len(result)): 
            area = top_val * (i - result[0] - 1 )  
        max_area = max(area, max_area)  
    return max_area  
# Returns area of the largest rectangle  
# with all 1s in A  
def maxRectangle(A): 
    # Calculate area for first row and initialize it as result  
    result = maxHist(A[0])  
    # iterate over row to find maximum rectangular area considering each row as histogram  
    for i in range(1, R): 
        for j in range(C): 
            # if A[i][j] is 1 then add A[i -1][j]  
            if (A[i][j]): 

                A[i][j] += A[i - 1][j]  
        # Update result if area with current row (as last row) of rectangle) is more  
        result = max(result, maxHist(A[i]))  
    return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rectangle that corresponds to line `max_area = max(area, max_area)` it is rectangle with height `top_val` and width `i` (or `i - result.top() - 1`) with right-bottom coordinate `i` (in `maxHist`) by column and `i` (in `maxRectangle` function) by row.

**ATTENTION**: please use C++ version from site, because Python 3 incorrect (it is not stack):

```py
    python = []
...
        if (len(result) == 0) or (row[result[0]] <= row[i]): 
            result.append(i) 
            i += 1
```

compared with C++ version:

```cpp
    stack<int> result; 
...
        if (result.empty() || row[result.top()] <= row[i]) 
            result.push(i++);
```

You can check it on test:

```
    A = [[0, 1, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 1, 1],
         [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```